# Is it possible to delete a javascript Blob from cache?

Tags: javascript, performance

Sometimes I no longer need a blob and its "createObjectURL", how can I completely erase it from existence so that it no longer takes up memory ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL

Comment: Yes! Exactly! Google always fails to give me results I actually need.

Comment: No problem, but it's Google I used.  I'll explain, as it might help for future.  I searched for `createObjectURL`, the top result was from MDN (Mozilla), that's always a good start, as MDN docs are top notch.  On that link there was some information on memory management, and that's were it had the link to `revokeObjectURL`.

Comment: _"Google always fails to give me results I actually need"_ - MDNs documentation of [`.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) mentions `.revokeObjectURL()` in the first _three_ sentences...

Answer (score -1):

As was stated by the user "Keith":
developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL

Comment: Please post your answer here. Avoid "link only" answers.